# Unable to pin volume bars to bottom of chart

Tags: pine-script

Created a custom Volume indicator in Pine Script, but I am unable to pin it to the bottom of the chart. I would like it to display the same way as the default volume indicator.

```
    study("BTC Dollar Volume", overlay=true, precision=0, scale = scale.none)

    showMA = input(title = "Show MA", type = bool, defval = false)
    length = input(title = "MA Length", type = integer, defval = 20)

    currentPrice = (open + close) / 2
    currentVolume = volume
    adjustedVolume = currentVolume * currentPrice


    barColor = iff(close>close[2], green, iff(close<=close[2], red, gray))

    plot(fixnan(adjustedVolume), style = columns, color = barColor, title="Volume")
    plot(showMA?sma(adjustedVolume, length):na, color = maroon)
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way to replace default volume indicator with a custom one.